# Next.js routing for slug urls e.g. site.com/username

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I'm trying to route so that each username has a profile page e.g site.com/jack or site.com/jill

(The username info is being pulled from an API which will also have the user ID and email)

Would appreciate a guide on what direction to go in as I'm a complete Next.js noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends how you have your pages folder, if you have pages > [name].js or pages > [name] > index.js , you can take it from context.query of getServerSideProps

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
     const { name } = context.query;
return {
props: {
name
}
}
     
}
```